# Impala convert timestamp AM/PM

Tags: hive, impala

I have table in hive with string in 12 hrs format
in which data is appended every day. I don't have control over hive table. Need to expose as view in impala after conversion.
to_timestamp() doesn't support AM/PM format.

Do we have a better way to convert string in 12 hrs format to timestamp.

came across this function which supports AM/PM.which support ISO SQL:2016 standard patterns.

**CAST(expression AS type FORMAT pattern)**

[impala conversion functions](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_conversion_functions.html)

This function is not supported by the impala version I am using.

The other ways I came across:

1. To add 12hrs to hh:mm if it is PM.
2. Convert it to 24hrs format in Hive  to other table or view using unix_timestamp and have it through impala(require to expose table as view in impala)

Answer (score 0):

can you use below function?
This will give you from string with am/pm to a date time format data.

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(string_with_ampm, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'))
```

Example

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('01/25/2021 09:58:37 AM', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')) c 
union 
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('01/25/2021 07:58:37 PM', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'))
```

Result
[image]

Comment: This query only works in hive, not in impala, I am directly trying to convert in impala. Impala doesn't support "a" in time format. the only thing I am left with is those two way I mentioned.